# Need access username from another table in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have two tables in the database one is `UserAuth` and the other is `CarAdd`, but I need to show `UserName` from the `UserAuth` table in my `CarAdd` dataGridView1 section.

This method shows all data from my `CarAdd` table:

```
void Bindata()
{
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from CarAdd", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sd.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

But, now I need to show the username from the `UserAuth` table in the dataGridView1 section.

I have tried this code:

```
void BindataUserName()
{
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UsreAuth where UserName='UserName'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sd.Fill(dt);

        // dataGridView1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

Here is my save click button, actually I need to save and show username on dataGridView1 after click this button:

```
private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        if (carid.Text != "" && cartype.Text != "" && model.Text != "" && intime.Text!="" && outtime.Text!="" && slotgroup.Text!="")
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                string newcon = "insert into CarAdd (carid, cartype, carmodel, duration, payment, slot_book, insertdate) values ('" + carid.Text + "','" + cartype.Text + "','" + model.Text + "', '" +txtduration.Text+ "','" +txtpayment.Text+ "','"+ slotgroup.Text +"' ,getdate())";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(newcon, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Successfully inserted");
                Bindata();
                // TimeShow();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                 con.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid credentials");
        }
}
```

**Note**: I have created a WPF Windows application for this project

Thank you!

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Since `UserName` is an attribute in the `UserAuth` table, the SQL query must be modified accordingly to fetch it.

```
SELECT UserName
FROM UserAuth
```

So for the `Bindatausername()` method, the `SqlCommand` should be changed to the following:

```
void BindataUserName()
{
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select UserName from UserAuth where UserName='UserName'", con);
```

Comment: ok, then how can I show UserName with "Lebel"  from the database UserAuth table!

Comment: You can query for the `UserName` that is "Lebel" by modifying the query to the one below.
`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select UserName from UserAuth where UserName='Lebel'", con);`